# Prolog list of transitive pairs

Tags: list, prolog

I've been trying to solve the following problem for a while now, but can't seem to find the right solution.

Lets say there is a function test(X,Y,Z) such that X is a single pair of numbers, Y is a list of pairs, and Z is the resulting list of transitive pairs.

For example:

```
test((1,5), [(7,3),(5,2),(5,9)], Z).

Z = [(1,2),(1,9)]
```

(because of transitivity 1->5->2 and 1->5->9)

So far I've managed to create the following code:

```
test(_,[],_):- false.
test((X1,C),[(C,Y2)|_],(X1,Y2)).
test((X1,X2),[_|YT],Result) :- test((X1,X2),YT,Result).
```

It returns each individual result pair like so:

```
Z = (1, 2) ;
Z = (1, 9) ;
```

But I can't seem to return them all into a single list like in the example above:

```
Z = [(1,2),(1,9)]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not building the list of transitive pairs. You're just returning a single pair as the third argument of `test/3`.

Here's one possible solution:

I made a predicate to handle comparing pairs and describing their transitive marriage, so that i didn't have to juggle those tuples in the subsequent rules:

```
transit((X,T), (T,Y), (X,Y)).
```

Then it's just a matter of standard list processing with recursive predicates:

```
t(_, [], []).
t(X, [T|ToTransit], [Y|Transited]) :-
    transit(X,T,Y),
    t(X,ToTransit,Transited).
t(X, [T|ToTransit], Transited) :-
    \+ transit(X,T,_),
    t(X,ToTransit, Transited).
```

Of course, once you have a predicate like `transit/3` that defines the relation, you can also do something like

```
findall( TP,
         ( member(T, [(2,2), (2,5), (1,5)]), transit((1,2), T, TP) ),
         Tps).
```

Comment: I would replace the `t(X, [T], [Y]) :-...` with `t(_, [], []).` :)

Comment: I'll make the change. I see the latter pattern is generally preferred -- is this just because it eliminates the need for the added clause in the ground definition?

Comment: Here it covers the "empty" case which otherwise isn't covered.